# Write MATLAB string data to csv , and then call csv data from python as string

Tags: python, string, matlab, csv

To convert MATLAB data to csv my code is:

```
M={'It is raining since morning'}
csvwrite('data.csv',M)
```

which saves the sentence like single character in single cell

```
| I | t | | i | s | | r | a | i | n | i | n | g |......
```

And when I am calling it from Python, my code is:

```
import csv
with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in readCSV:
        a=(row)
        print(a)
```

which gives result:

```
['I', 't', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'r', 'a', 'i', 'n', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ', 's', 'i', 'n', 'c', 'e', ' ', 'm', 'o', 'r', 'n', 'i', 'n', 'g']
```

All I want is to save this sentence as a string like this, `"It is raining Since Morning"`.

And further I want to convert this text into speech, if I am sending this data for conversion

```
>> ['I', 't', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'r', 'a', 'i', 'n', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ', 's', 'i', 'n', 'c', 'e', ' ', 'm', 'o', 'r', 'n', 'i', 'n', 'g']
```

It gives the error :

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: `print(''.join(a))`

Comment: CSV stands for Comma Separated **VALUE**. You're not separating values. Don't cram a round peg into a square hole. Just use `fwrite()` to write to any string-supporting format (e.g. txt, dat)

Comment: @Adriaan my matlab knowledge is almost rusted away, but the python-side answer and my comment are fixing something that it seems you can avoid upstream. If you post an answer to stop that, I'd prefer to have that voted up against fixing downstream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to save a string into a format which is build to support numbers. Don't cram a round peg into a square hole, instead get a round hole, such as `.txt`:

```matlab
M='It is raining since morning'; % Why a cell? Character arrays work better
FiD = fopen('data.txt','w+'); % Create and open file for writing
fprintf(FiD,M); % write data
fclose(FiD); % Close file
```

I have no idea how to work in Python, but parsing pure strings form a suitable format shouldn't be too much of a hassle.

Comment: What would the file look like here? Just a regular single line of text? I can give you the corresponding python side if I know that

Comment: @roganjosh a single line of text as it currently stands. OP might want extra lines or something, then a line break needs to be added using `\n` at the end of each sentence, i.e. `fprintf(FiD,[M'\n']);`

Comment: Ok, I'll put the code in but I'm on a phone so you may have to fix the formatting

Comment: @roganjosh since I do not speak any Python, I cannot vouch for the correctness of any code written in that. Please do write your own, separate answer. You can link to mine if you want of course.

Comment: @roganjosh yes the file is a simple text file with sentence kindly let me know python code for string.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the MATLAB side, but since a string is iterable it looks like it's interpreting the string as a list of characters that you want to save then making those comma separated, so your actual CSV file probably looks like this if you open it in a text editor:

```
I,t, ,i,s, ,r,a,i,n,i,n,g, ,s,i,n,c,e, ,m,o,r,n,i,n,g
```

To save just the single string to a CSV try making it the single element of an array to get the following text in the CSV

```
It is raining since morning
```

That said CSV doesn't really seem like the right format for your use case.  Why not just a simple .txt file?

On the python side, if you get the above to work loading with `csv` as you have will give you a list with a singe item:

```
print(a)

Out: ['It is raining since morning']
```

Alternately you can create the string you want from the list of characters with:

```
a = ''.join(a)
```

Also, side note: `strip` won't do anything to that string since there is no leading or trailing whitespace.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score -2):

According to [Matlab's documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html#mw_12ae567d-3ac0-42f2-b5e6-dee7125f33cb) for csvwrite it only supports numeric matrices. You are better off using [xlswrite](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html) which supports strings. Python also has the ability to read in excel files so the switch from csv to xls should be trivial.

Comment: Writing to Excel files is A) overkill, B) pointless when not using it in Excel. Just use a low-level `fwrite`